# Select value from single value from multiplie vlaue column in mysql

Tags: mysql

For EXAMPLE 
 Table: Datauser

```
Plans
--------
109,1009,178
```

Select  rows   from  Datauser  where plans    = 109 only .

Comment: And the query you have tried? Please learn the basics of sql queries.

Comment: post your tried query and your table details?

Comment: Thanks for quick response .But my  filed name is 'plan' and   multiple plan id 'value  separated  by  , in  single rows  for . 109,1009,178,1098 etc

Comment: you can use array to get your results

Comment: can we use custom serach in mysql for feching these record.Yes array is last option to get final result  and we user in _array  in php

Comment: sorry?custom search means?

Comment: you just declare you plans field in array and then you can easily get the result by using in_array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used LIKE query. Please try this query:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM Datauser 
WHERE Plans LIKE "109" OR Plans LIKE "109,%" OR Plans LIKE "%,109" 
OR Plans LIKE "%,109,%"
```

Which simply means that there can be 4 conditions in the column:

plans column has only '109' in it, or ',109,' in it or '109,' in it, or ',109' in it.

Comment: We can also use find_in_set(106,plans) ..google finding

Answer (score 0):

Use this ..

```
SELECT * FROM `Datauser`  WHERE `plans` = 109
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response .But my  field name is 'plan' and   multiple plan id 'value  separated  by  , in  single rows  for . 109,1009,178,1098 etc